# DeprecationWarning: using `oa_ndim == 0` when `op_axes` is NULL is deprecated

Tags: python, pandas

How do I prevent this exception?

```
C:\Anaconda\envs\p33\lib\site-packages\numexpr\necompiler.py:742: DeprecationWarning: using `oa_ndim == 0` when `op_axes` is NULL is deprecated. Use `oa_ndim == -1` or the MultiNew iterator for NumPy <1.8 compatibility
  return compiled_ex(*arguments, **kwargs)
```

It is generated when I do the following:

```
df = pd.DataFrame( np.random.randn(1000,59))
df2=df**2
```

It does not seem to occur if I make a smaller dataframe.  e.g.

```
df = pd.DataFrame( np.random.randn(1000,10))
```

My pandas version is 0.13.1
My numpy version is 1.8.1

Comment: Possible [related issue](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/6119).

Answer (score 3):

I managed to fix the problem by updating numexpr.  I did this using Conda from the command line:

```
conda update -n p33 numexpr
```